# Программирование avr мк atmega8

Tags: c, avr

Помогите с написанием кода на си.
Возникла проблема с кодом для динамической индикации на 3-х разрядах. А именно не могу понять как погасить лишние ноли спереди числа ( ненужные знакоместа). Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: это погасит в `x` все кроме трех младших разрядов `x &= 0b111`

Comment: А можно ответ чуть по полнее?

Comment: И вопрос в том что у меня порты в разброс.

Comment: DDRB|=(1<<0)|(1<<4)|(1<<5);
 PORTB&=~((1<<0)|(1<<4)|(1<<5));// разряды индикатора